# Can Not Save to My Documents in Office

Tags: windows, roaming-profile

We have AD environment, which all users have a roaming profile in a file server. My problem is when a user open office document and want to save it in my documents it says Access Denied on \myserver\users$, and actually the user profile is in \myserver\users$*username*. 
 the default work location setting point to correct location \myserver\users$*username*, but when save popup message appears and click on my documents it says access denied.

**Note:**
I can open my documents from desktop without any problem

Comment: Are you redirecting the Documents folder for the users?

Comment: Yes I am, the Documents folder on a centralized server

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of this is that Word is NOT running as the user you think it is.

This can often happen if your running Word (and other apps) from a dedicated application server, which may be being accessed with a differently impersonated set of credentials than the credentials that your user is logged in with.

A quick and reasonably foolproof way to check this, is to set up a linux samba server and attach it to the same AD, save a file from word into a share on that samba server, then log into the Linux command line, list the files and see exactly what user it believes the file was saved as.

This works better than saving it on a windows machine, because in the windows environment impersonation gets in the way and can often label a file with the intended user, but impersonate with a different security SID.

Things to look at:

1. Check the user that word is running as
2. Compare the user that word files are saved as, with files that are saved from desktop
3. Temporarily set user permissions on a user share to "Everyone, Full control" then re-test a save in word does it work?  (If it does then it's screaming out that it's a user impersonation problem)

Comment: Thank you shawty, the application is running locally in the user machine. This problem just happened when you try to save an office docs and then choose my documents from save menu

Comment: Exactly, so what you'll need to do then is ask your system administrator to verify that word is saving as the correct user.  A common mistake I see admins make, is to have word running as an admin, then they block the admin account from writing to users shares for security.  If your only a user, then you'll need help for your network admins to do this.